# What to do about repeated self-vandalization?

Tags: discussion, support, vandalism

Sorry if this is answered somewhere else -- it's my first time on meta.

There is [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951822/math-is-subjective-change-my-mind) which is being repeatedly vandalized by the OP and someone else (perhaps a friend?). Regardless, It seems me and some other MSE users have all been involved with repeatedly rolling back the changes, only to get fed up with the endeavor and leave.

I've flagged the question as "needing moderator attention", and gave a similar description to the one above. I've never seen this kind of behavior before, so I'm not sure if there's anything else to do about it.

**Edit:** It seems the post has finally been locked, but I'm still curious if there's anything more I could have done. It seems there's a policy on [edit wars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/) that may be relevant.

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Flag, as you did, and at least two others of us have flagged.  The more flags, the more attention mods give to it.  We can roll back a few times, and inform the user, but ultimately, when the OP is persistent, flagging the questions for mod attention, with details, is the most appropriate action to take.

Comment: That question had 36 versions in a matter of a few hours! No way an edit war should have gone on that way. Flag, flag, flag, and find something more constructive to do.